# Number theory problem that came from Waring's problem

Tags: number-theory

I saw this problem in wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions#Unsolved_problem):

Are there positive integers $k\geq6$ such that

\begin{equation}
3^k-2^k\left \lfloor{(\frac{3}{2})^k}\right \rfloor>2^k-\left \lfloor{(\frac{3}{2})^k}\right \rfloor-2?
\end{equation}

My attempt:

I just want to find at least one number that satisfy this inequality. I found there is high precision calculator at https://keisan.casio.com/calculator. It doesn't have floor, but it has ceiling function, so we can use $\left \lceil{(\frac{3}{2})^k-1}\right \rceil$ instead of $\left \lfloor{(\frac{3}{2})^k}\right \rfloor$. However, the calculater is unable to calculate above inequality for $k=1000$. So I rewrote it to a different form:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&3^k-2^k\left \lfloor{1.5^k}\right \rfloor>2^k-\left \lfloor{1.5^k}\right \rfloor-2,\\
&1.5^k-\left \lfloor{1.5^k}\right \rfloor>1-2^{-k}\left \lfloor{1.5^k}\right \rfloor-2^{-k+1},\\
&1.5^k-\left \lfloor{1.5^k}\right \rfloor>-2^{-k}\left \lfloor{1.5^k}\right \rfloor-2^{-k+1}+2+\left \lfloor{1.5^k}\right \rfloor-1-\left \lfloor{1.5^k}\right \rfloor,\\
&1.5^k-\left \lfloor{1.5^k}\right \rfloor>(-2^{-k}+1)(\left \lfloor{1.5^k}\right \rfloor+2)-1-\left \lfloor{1.5^k}\right \rfloor,\\
&1+1.5^k>(-2^{-k}+1)(\left \lfloor{1.5^k}\right \rfloor+2).
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Here $\left \lfloor{1.5^k}\right \rfloor+2=\left \lceil{1.5^k+1}\right \rceil$, so

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&1+1.5^k>(-2^{-k}+1)(\left \lfloor{1.5^k}\right \rfloor+2),\\
&1+1.5^k>(-2^{-k}+1)(\left \lceil{1.5^k+1}\right \rceil),\\
&\frac{1+1.5^k}{\left \lceil{1+1.5^k}\right \rceil}>1-2^{-k},\\
&2^{-k}-1+\frac{1+1.5^k}{\left \lceil{1+1.5^k}\right \rceil}>0.
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Now we can use online calculator and see that for $k=1000$ last inequality holds. Are my calculations right? And can we trust to this online calculator?

Comment: Note, the Wikipedia entry says "none are known," so it will indeed be of interest if you succeed in finding such a number $k$. Hardy and Wright (which is referenced in the Wikipedia entry) is well worth a look if you can get a hold of a copy; on page 337 they say that values of $k$ up to 200,000 had been checked computationally, in a paper published in 1964.